# 404 not found fetching rollouts

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, grpc

I have a GRPC service running in a private GKE cluster with a [limited access to public endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#custom_subnet). I have my own VPC and subnet. I am deploying my service and endpoint as the docs describe, but I am hitting this error when the esp container starts up. I am using my own service account that should have all the permissions and my cluster has the following oauth scopes:

```
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append
```

I am getting the following error, even though the name matches as in my YAML file.

`ERROR:Fetching rollouts failed (status code 404, reason Not Found, url https://servicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/services/<name>.cloud.goog/rollouts?filter=status=SUCCESS)`

EDIT: 
This is the container spec for the esp container

```
containers:
    - name: esp
     image: gcr.io/endpoints-release/endpoints-runtime:1
     args: [
       "-P", "9000",
       "-a", "grpc://127.0.0.1:50051",
       "-s", "<service-name>.cloud.goog",
       "--rollout_strategy", "managed",
       "--service_account_key=/etc/creds/service-account-creds.json"
     ]
```

Comment: can you provide more details such as the pod spec? I assume you are using GKE private cluster, did you configure private access for your VPC? Are your pods able to reach ANY Google API?

Comment: @PatrickW I updated with the container spec, it is a private cluster with limited access to public basically through master authorized networks. I don't believe I added private access to vpc, it doesn't seem to need it since it's able to access cloud registry and endpoints. The issue it seems to have is it can't find the config for my grpc server. Even though in the history for my endpoint I can't see the configs

Comment: I would still check to see if the pod can resolve the URL to an IP period. If it does, check if the config can be found from outside the cluster

Comment: How can I do that? For more info, the other container in my pod containing my server implementation can reach MySQL. So I'm less concerned about resolving gcp endpoints but I'm willing to try. How can I test that or the config from outside cluster. Thanks again for all your help

Comment: if it can resolve other GCP API endpoints, then that is likely not the issue. Can you confirm the config is present? Try using a [direct API call](https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/service-management/reference/rest/v1/services/get) to list the service to make sure the URL resolves correctly

Comment: So I tried it using `gcloud` instead of direct API and got for my personal account: 
gcloud endpoints services describe bifold.endpoints.wildfire-app-backend.cloud.goog
generation: '9'
producerProjectId: wildfire-app-backend
serviceConfig:
  documentation: {}
  id: 2019-10-30r0
  legacy:
    apiV1Name: bifold.endpoints.wildfire-app-backend.cloud.goog
    devconsole:
      consoleApi: NEW
  migration: {}
  name: bifold.endpoints.wildfire-app-backend.cloud.goog
  title: Bifold gRPC API
  usage: {}
serviceName: bifold.endpoints.wildfire-app-backend.cloud.goog

Comment: and from the service account: 
producerProjectId: wildfire-app-backend
serviceName: bifold.endpoints.wildfire-app-backend.cloud.goog

Comment: it seems like there is something missing that the service account can't get the remainder of the info, but when i did check-iam-policy both personal and service account used in gke have the same policies

Comment: @PatrickW I also created a non private cluster in my VPC and I got the same issue. Not sure what is the cause of this

Comment: Do you and the service account have the same iam permissions?

Comment: The permissions for my account are: App Engine Admin,
App Engine Code Viewer,
App Engine Deployer,
App Engine Service Admin,
Project Billing Manager,
Cloud Build Service Account,
Cloud Build Editor,
Cloud Build Viewer,
Compute OS Admin Login,
Service Account User,
Owner,
Organization Administrator,
Project Mover,
Storage Admin,
and my service account: Cloud SQL Client,
Editor,
Role Viewer,
Logs Writer,
Monitoring Metric Writer,
Owner,
Service Management Administrator,
Service Config Editor,
Service Controller,
Storage Admin,
Storage Object Viewer.

Comment: Those are very different permissions. This is likely an IAM issue

Answer (score 0):

since you are getting the error 404 this scenario is related to IAM permissions as Patrick W mentioned. I suggest you take a look on this document where you can find useful information regarding to API permissions [1].

Also, this could be related to Google Service Management services.rollouts.list requiring authorization token, which can be read from the metadata server or the service account key file. You may refer to this page[2] for more information.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/api-permissions

[2] https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/service-management/reference/rest/v1/services.rollouts/list